# How to handle for browser refresh, back button

Tags: javascript, refresh, handle, back

- I'm developing a site for internet banking system, once logged in I have main page(session is maintain here) and few tabs/links as child for the main page,
- I already have js to kill the session or to logout, but the problem is with the event handler
- when the page is refreshed or back button is click, I have to handle as below

  ```
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
     if( confirm("This page will be close") ){
           //called the logout fn to kill session
     }
  }
  ```
- the above js works fine, but the problem with the above code is that its called whenever other links/tabs are clicked in the main page, so its keep on logout
- I'm sorry if my question is not clear or duplicate, do anyone can suggest the way to handle this
- for your info, I'm using jsp and servlet with js, this project cannot be used jquery and cannot disable back button and refresh button

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please let us know what bank this is for, so we can avoid it!

Answer (score 0):

- You can save previously visited URL (information) as a hashed input
  tag in next page, so whenever you are going to visit it again you can
  understand that back button has been pressed.
- Another solution would be using *document.referrer*.
- You can also use a plugin with JQuery named *History*. It is
  available at https://github.com/browserstate/History.js